# No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `sqrt`

Tags: haskell

I'm doing some basic work in Haskell and don't understand why this isn't compiling. Here's the error:

```
shapes.hs:35:11:
    No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    In the expression: sqrt (hd * hd + vd * vd)
    In an equation for `d': d = sqrt (hd * hd + vd * vd)
    In the expression:
      let
        hd = xc - x
        vd = yc - y
        d = sqrt (hd * hd + vd * vd)
      in if d <= r then True else False
```

Related code:

```
type Point = (Int,Int)
data Figure = Rect Point Point | Circ Point Int
inside :: Point -> Figure -> Bool
inside (x,y) (Rect (left,bot) (right,top)) =
  if x <= left && x >= right &&
     y <= bot && y >= top
  then True
  else False
inside (x,y) (Circ (xc,yc) r) =
  let hd = xc - x
      vd = yc - y
      d = sqrt (hd*hd + vd*vd) in -- line 35 is here
  if d <= r then True else False
```

The sqrt function's type is `Floating a => a -> a -> a`. Doesn't Num auto convert to Floating, or is this not the problem?

Comment: As a general note, Haskell almost *never* does any auto-conversion of anything. It's all manual. If something is an `Int` and you want a `Float`, *you* have to call something to do the conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the `Circ` handling code to this and it will typecheck:

```
inside (x,y) (Circ (xc,yc) r) =
  let hd = fromIntegral $ xc - x
      vd = fromIntegral $ yc - y
      d = sqrt (hd*hd + vd*vd) in 
  if d <= (fromIntegral r) then True else False
```

The type of `sqrt` is `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` and you have to do proper type conversion using `fromIntegral` to make it typecheck.

Comment: Wow I tried `fromIntegral` on everything but `r`. I don't understand this type system.

Comment: @Czipperz It's simple, with experience you will get intuition. In your case `d` already has a type of `Floating a` whereas `r` was still `Int. So, all you had to do was do the type conversion there.

Comment: in every other language I've programmed in, there has never been an error with upcasting. This seems outright strange to me.

Comment: @Czipperz: what does "upcasting" mean in Haskell?

Comment: @ErikAllik in Haskell? I don't think it is a concept in Haskell. Upcasting means that you expand the memory used by a value to that of the thing it is being multiplied/added/subtracted/divided against.

Comment: but the cast from `int` to `float` isn't merely a question of expanding memory in the first place. and even if it were, Haskell wouldn't "cast" an `Int` to `Floating a => a` for you automatically, just as it wouldn't cast anything else ever (not even e.g. `Int` to `Integer`).

Comment: One of the reasons you use haskell is that you know what type things are at all time, which rules out the possibility of converting a type to another automatically.